# gridview rowdatabound event in winforms?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, datagrid, data-binding

in asp.net we can handle the RowDataBound event of the GridView control. this event fires when every row is added to the gridview.

i want to be able to handle this event in the gridview in a winforms application but i cannot find a similar event. my question is what is the event name that allows me to do the same as RowDataBound in asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataGridView doesn't have the same event handling as in ASP.NET.

What you could do is handle `RowsAdded` event, but note that more than one row can be added when this event fires. An example:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = e.RowIndex; i < e.RowCount + e.RowIndex; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Row " + i.ToString() + " added");
    }
}
```

Also, this event is a bit 'buggy' - at the moment when it's databound it may fire more than once for each row, but afterwards it behaves correctly - when you add a new row to data source, it's fired only once.

But, I should probably mention (even if that's not your original question), that if you used this event in ASPX to handle output formatting, than here an equivalent would actually be `CellFormatting` event - this event is called whenever the cells needs to display it's value.

Answer (score 0):

There's no exact counterpart of the RowDataBound event for the WinForms 
DataGridView. But if you'd like to change the displayed text before the 
value of a cell is rendered, you could handle the ***CellFormatting*** event of 
the DataGridView .